# HTML5 Fullscreen Like vimeo.com on Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, fullscreen, mediaelement, mediaelement.js

Notified today that vimeo on chrome push the F11 button for you !
I haven't found any info on how it work but it's very cool.
I'm using mediaelement.js for now, is they planning to implement this ?

To try it open a video on vimeo, make sure you are in HTML5 (bottom right of post, on top right of the comments) and click "Switch to HTML5 player"
Play a video in a real fullscreen !

Answer (score 2):

Chrome dev channel now comes with the [fullscreen API](http://peter.sh/2011/08/fullscreen-api-enhanced-element-highlighting-and-progress-on-flexbox/)

Sample usage:

```
<video width="300" src="movie.webm" controls></video>
<button onclick="enterFullscreen()">Get Huge!</button>

function enterFullscreen() {
  var elem = document.querySelector('body');
  elem.onwebkitfullscreenchange = function(e) {
    console.log("Entered fullscreen!");
    elem.onwebkitfullscreenchange = onFullscreenExit;
  };
  elem.webkitRequestFullScreen();
}
```

See this [slide deck](http://smustalks.appspot.com/keynote-india-devfest-11/#25) for usage, and here's a [demo](http://smustalks.appspot.com/keynote-india-devfest-11/demos/fullscreen.html) of the API in action.